# Android: getting location from network when wifi is turned off

Tags: java, android, gps

I have to send user's location via sms. I want to get location first from gps and if gps in not available then it should send location from network. But my app sends two messages at the same time one from gps and one from network although the wifi network is turned off in my device I don't know from where it is getting location. 
I want it to use only gps first and if it doesn't find gps then send message from network.            Here is my code.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener  {

long time = 0 * 1000; 
long distance = 0; 
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
Location location;
String device_id;
double latitude ;
double longitude;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;
String phoneNo = "+923300000009";

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("alarm receiver....");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);

    //Start App On device restart
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Intent App = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(App);
    }

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    device_id = tm.getDeviceId();  // returns IMEI number   }

try {

    locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // getting GPS status
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

     // getting network status
     isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
        // no network provider is enabled
    } else {
        this.canGetLocation = true;
        // First check from GPS Provider

        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,time,distance, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        String Text =  " From GPS: Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +" Longitude = " + location.getLongitude() + " Device Id: " + device_id;
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                        this.abortBroadcast(); 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
       if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,time,distance, this);
            Log.d("Network", "Network");
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    String Text =  " From Network: Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +" Longitude = " + location.getLongitude() + " Device Id: " + device_id;
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                    this.abortBroadcast(); 

                }
            }
        }
   } 

catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}  
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // this.location = location;

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: Are you taking mobile network (gprs, 3g, 4g etc.) into consideration?

Comment: You are getting location from your GPS, which has nothing to do with WiFi connected or disconnected

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Yes my device has 3G enabled. Is it getting location from 3G

Comment: @JibranKhan you are right but if gps is enabled then it should not go not execute the (isNetworkEnabled) condition, why it is doing so. Please guide me if something is wrong in my code.

Comment: before your isNetworkEnabled condition, you have checked isGPSEnabled so it will execute that piece of code and will get you the location

Comment: the network location is coming from the cell tower of your carrier!

Comment: @konainali Yes, location is received from 3G (and the like) as well, though it's much more inaccurate than wifi.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja gprs, 3g, 4g has nothing to do with network location.

Comment: http://wrongfulconvictionsblog.org/2012/06/01/cell-tower-triangulation-how-it-works/ read this

Comment: @MuhammadBabar how can I Stop it from getting location from cell tower if the gps is enabled.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar What I meant was that the device will get a location if it's connected to a cell tower as well.

Comment: @konainali simply don't register for `NETWORK LOCATION`. In your code put a `return ;` statement where when you find location from GPS.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar i'm new to programming and android. I would appreciate if you show me where to use return statement.

Comment: inside the block of `if (isGPSEnabled)` then `if (location != null)` at the very last line of the block i.e { } put `return ;`;